# How to use filter in JSF richface data table as "Contains" or "Ends With"

Tags: jsf, filter, datatable, richfaces

I am using JSF richface. I am using Filters in data table.

```
<rich:column width="50px" label="Item Name" align="center" 
filterBy="#{list.itemName}"  filterEvent="onkeyup"
filterValue="#{Bean.itemFilter}"    filterType="custom">                                    
    <h:inputText id="item"  value="#{list.itemName}" styleClass="rsInput" disabled="true" />
</rich:column>
```

Here #{Bean.itemFilter} is a string variable. I have no idea about this.

It works like "Starts with" for given search keyword. 
If a letter 'A' is typed, it brings item name starts with 'A'. But I need to get item name contains 'A'(may be at anywhere).

I need to use filter like "contains" or "Ends with". How can I approach this?

Answer (score 3):

`@filterBy` is set to use "starts with" as the filtering method, if you want different filtering use `@filterMethod` - referencing a method that accepts Object and returns boolean, or `@filterExpression` - simple EL expression that evaluates to a boolean. ([rich:column docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/rich/column.html))